# what is the @ after the permissions for in ls -l on a mac?

Tags: macos, mac, ls, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ls -la symbolics… what does that last symbol mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean)

Consider the following output from ls -l on OS X 10.5.8

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  staff    102 Aug 26 20:21 downloads
drwxrwxrwx@ 10 user  staff    340 Aug 26 20:12 images
```

Can anybody tell me what the @ represents at the end of the permissions section, and also how to disable/enable it. I guess this this has something to do with the directory listing permissions, as when I'm running a PHP script in Apache that needs to access a folder without the @ bit set, it doesn't list the directory contents.

Thanks!