# ls -la symbolics... what does that last symbol mean?

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does the @ mean on the output of ls on os x terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/155458/what-does-the-mean-on-the-output-of-ls-on-os-x-terminal)

when I type `ls -la` I get this familiar output...

```
drwxr-xr-x+  38 kent  staff       1292 Nov  6 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  admin        170 Aug 14 14:11 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 kent  staff         16 Jun 18 14:13 .AB64CF89
-rw-------    1 kent  staff          3 May  5  2009 .CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@   1 kent  staff      15364 Nov  6 11:11 .DS_Store
```

my question is about the file settings on the far left eg:

```
drwxr-xr-x+
```

I know that the first char 'd' means directory.
and the next 9 chars I understand as well (permissions)
but what is the final char in this field? (empty or `+` or `@` )