# What does the @ in ls -al mean?

Tags: unix, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ls -la symbolics… what does that last symbol mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean)

What does the `@` in the below execution of `ls -al` mean?

```
atom:Lib fak$ ls -al
total 1056
drwxr-xr-x  5 fak  staff     170 Dec 24 13:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 fak  staff     204 Dec 24 13:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 fak  staff  121393 Oct  3 14:05 HtmlAgilityPack.XML
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 fak  staff  101376 Oct  3 14:05 HtmlAgilityPack.dll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 fak  staff  315392 Dec 24 13:19 MySql.Data.dll
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That indicates extended attributes are applied to the file.  You can use xattr to modify/view those attributes.

See: [ls -la symbolics... what does that last symbol mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean)

Answer (score 11):

It means the file has extended attributes. You can use the `-@` switch to ls to view them, and `xattr` to modify/view them.

example:

```
ls -@ HtmlAgilityPack.XML
```