# Why are some files in ls -l on Mac OSX (Snow Leopard) tagged with "@"?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, shell, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the @ in ls -al mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/87467/what-does-the-in-ls-al-mean)

When doing an ls -l some files are tagged with "@" like this:

-rw-r--r--@  1 master  staff   2074042 Feb  3 19:26 openssh-5.1p1-vs-openbsd.diff

What does that mean?

Comment: Duplicate of, among others, "What does the @ in ls -al mean?" at http://superuser.com/questions/87467/what-does-the-in-ls-al-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are extended attributes.   ls -l@ shows them (mostly they are flags to indicate that the file is coming from the internet, in those cases, when opening the file (or installing a DMG) MacOS will ask if you *really* want to open it).  The xattr command allows you to change them.

There is another one too.  ls -lO (upper case O) shows the flags set via chflags command.  ls -lO@ shows the file in it's full glory.

Comment: I was sure I had chcked "man ls" *duh*

Comment: Personally, I use `ls -lOa@ehTi`. I like to just go for it... Oh yes, and even displaying all this information, the shell still runs circles around the Finder. Have to wonder what it's doing. :o