# what does @ mean in linux file

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does the @ mean on the output of ls on os x terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/155458/what-does-the-mean-on-the-output-of-ls-on-os-x-terminal)

I found this symbol `@` when I run `ls -al` in my home folder, what does it mean here?

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 yangchenyun  admin   238 Jul 19 16:32 Code
drwx------@ 25 yangchenyun  admin   850 Oct  2 20:08 Dropbox
```

Comment: [ls -la symbolics... what does that last symbol mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean/66724#66724), [What does the @ in ls -al mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/87467/what-does-the-in-ls-al-mean?lq=1), [Why are some files in ls -l on Mac OSX (Snow Leopard) tagged with "@"?](http://superuser.com/questions/105944/why-are-some-files-in-ls-l-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard-tagged-with?lq=1), et cetera. Please research for an answer before asking a question. The `ls` manpage has all the info, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `info ls`, section 10.1.2, *What information is listed* (from the manual for GNU coreutils 8.5):

```
 Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
 whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
 applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode
 bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is
 a printing character, then there is such a method.
```

So the `@` indicates that there exists an alternate access method on the file. This most likely means an ACL. Try `getfacl Dropbox` and see what you get.

You may need to install some package to get the ACL-related commands. In Debian, `getfacl` is provided by the `acl` package, so `sudo apt-get install acl` if it isn't installed already. Other distributions may or may not use the same package name.

Answer (score 0):

@ Seems to indicate extended attributes (at least in Mac OS X, see http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-userlevel/2007/Nov/msg00013.html)