# directory listing on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, permissions, ls

I dumped a bunch of files (music and otherwise) onto my shiny new Macbook, and since I'm more comfortable with linux than Mac (at this point) I tend to use the terminal.

I did a ls -al on the files I'd transfered, and some had an "@" at the end of the permissions string, and some did not.

Something like:

```
drwxrwxr--@ 93 user staff etc.
drwxrwxr-- 107 user staff etc.
```

The ones without "@" could be seen in Finder and accessed by other programs-- the "@" files and directories were invisible. Can anyone explain what the "@" means, and how to chmod (or whatever) so I can use these files? I assume it is some sort of system flag but I don't know how to unset it. Chmod 777 had no effect and I already own the files.

Thanks

Comment: See "ls -la symbolics… what does that last symbol mean?" at http://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This link](http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2008/12/24/what-is-the-significance-of-plus-and-at-in-mac-os-x-file-permission-tables/) explains how the '@' symbol is used to signify that the file has 'additional attributes' that can be seen by typing:

> xattr -l < filename >

The additional attributes are used to store extra information about the file. For example when a file is downloaded from the internet, it may contain an additional attribute that triggers the 'warning this file was downloaded..' message upon execution.

Answer (score 5):

As JT.WK said, the '@' indicates extended attributes attached to the file.  Try using `ls -lO@` on the files -- the `-O` shows file flags, and the `-@` shows the names (but not contents) of the extended attributes.  My guess is that you're going to see `com.apple.FinderInfo` xattrs, and the `hidden` flag (note: I'm assuming Mac OS X 10.5 or 10.6 here -- older versions didn't map the `invisible` Finder flag into a a file flag).  Assuming I'm right about that, you can clear the flag with:

```
chflags nohidden /path/to/file
```

(If you're using Mac OS X v10.4, Finder flags weren't nearly as accessible from the command line -- let me know and I'll see what I can come up with.)