# Greyed out folder in OS X

Tags: macos, permissions, finder

I installed the Intel compiler on my Mac (10.6), and it installed fine, but the folder in which it is installed (/opt, i.e. at the root) is not visible by default, and when I use the Finder "go to" feature, it appears, but as greyed out. What does it mean?

I also checked out the permissions, and the only odd thing is that there is an @ at the end of permissions. Any ideas?

I'm asking because while the Intel compiler is installed (all the files are there), I can't use it from XCode (3.2), and I'm wondering whether this could be why.

Comment: The @ denotes the existence of extended attributes, see <http://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean>

Answer (score 3):

Greyed out elements in the *Get Info* dialog mean that you don't have permissions to edit them. In this case, the folder belongs to `root`, and you don't have permissions to change them, unlike most of what's in your home folder, which belongs to your user account. Click the lock icon and enter an administrator's password to edit what you cannot ordinarily change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The folder is simply hidden.

To unhide it, do the following in the Terminal :

> sudo chflags nohidden /opt

To hide it again :

> sudo chflags hidden /opt

Comment: the -R  options make this recursive.