# what does the @ symbol mean in ls -l directory listing?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, freebsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ls -la symbolics… what does that last symbol mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean)

When I run ls -l on my mac I see two .yml files:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 aa  staff    6 Apr 15 05:50 s1.yml
-rw-r--r--@ 1 aa  staff  362 Apr 15 05:49 s3.yml
```

same owner, same permissions but one has a @ at the end of the permisions.  The one with the @ shows up in my editor, the one without does not.  So there must be some significance.  How can I turn on the @ for the file without it?  I selected the files in the finder and did get info and everything looks identical between the two files.

Comment: A quick Google search reveals: http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=93462

Answer (score 25):

It indicates that the file has extended attributes, it is mac specific. 
The command xattr deals with those attributes, so try xattr -h to see its parameters.

Comment: the -h flag brings up the help. to see the attributes, just do it without the -h flag. `xattr {file_name}`

Answer (score 20):

Those indicate extended attributes.  Try this:

```
$ ls -a -l -@
total 1576
drwxr-xr-x+ 76 paul  staff    2584 Apr 13 17:52 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  admin     170 Aug 22  2009 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 paul  staff   24580 Feb 28 22:07 .DS_Store
        com.apple.FinderInfo        32
```

Comment: _As a side note:_ it is possible to write options in a more _compact_ way. In the above case it would be like this:  `$ ls -al@ ` (i.e. grouping the options together).