# What's @ in OS X directory permissions?

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ls -la symbolics… what does that last symbol mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean)

Being unable to access my localhost via Parallels, I've found that the folder to which I was trying to access has permissions attributed `drwxr-xr-x@` and so all of its files and subdirectories.

Mind the @ symbol. What does it mean?

I've also discovered that using `mkdir` creates permissions without the @ symbol. These directories ARE accessible to the VM. I generally suspect the @.

Your ideas?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean