# What's the meaning of @ in ls -al?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ls -la symbolics… what does that last symbol mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean)

```
$ ls -al
-rw-r--r--@  1 john staff  2635 Oct 01 18:15 index.html

          ^
```

What's the mean of a `@` sign? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/30264/what-is-the-after-the-permissions-for-in-ls-l-on-a-mac-closed  http://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean and probably more

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/200498/whats-in-os-x-directory-permissions-closed