# What does the @ mean in the Mac OS X file permissions?

Tags: macos, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [what is the @ after the permissions for in ls -l on a mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/30264/what-is-the-after-the-permissions-for-in-ls-l-on-a-mac)
>   [ls -la symbolics… what does that last symbol mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/66722/ls-la-symbolics-what-does-that-last-symbol-mean)

Running a "ls -l" on a folder I get :

```
....
-rwxrwxr-x@ 1 me  staff   466676 Mar  6 05:38 pgsql.so  
-rwxrwxr-x@ 1 me  staff   709156 Mar  6 05:38 xcache.so  
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff      802 Jul 14 13:25 xdebug.a  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me  staff   274384 Jul 14 13:25 xdebug.so  
....
```

What does the '@' mean?